# Pass checkbox values to PHP using AJAX & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get this contact form to work with bootstrap alerts (for success), validation, ajax, and php.  My issue is sending the checkbox values to php.  The email does not submit as it sits.  if I comment out the jquery, ajax, and php with in regards to the checkboxes, it submits and I receive the email.  Please assist in getting the checkbox values to pass through using ajax and php.  I've updated both the php and ajax sections regarding the checkboxes.

Thanks

My Form Markup:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" data-validation-minchecked-minchecked="1" 
      data-validation-minchecked-message="Please choose at least one"id="q12_1" value="Website Design or Redesign"> Website Design or Redesign      
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" id="q12_2" value="eCommerce / Online Store"> eCommerce / Online Store
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"name="services[]" id="q12_3" value="Web Application Development"> Web Application Development                     
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"name="services[]" id="q12_4" value="Website Maintenance / Hosting"> Website Maintenance / Hosting
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"name="services[]" id="q12_5" value="Branding Services / Graphic Design"> Branding Services / Graphic Design                       
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
    /*
    Jquery Validation using jqBootstrapValidation
example is taken from jqBootstrapValidation docs 
*/
$(function() {

 $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation(
{
 preventSubmit: true,
 submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
  // something to have when submit produces an error ?
  // Not decided if I need it yet
 },
 submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
   // get values from FORM
   var name = $("input#name").val();  
   var email = $("input#email").val(); 
   var phone = $("input#phone").val(); 
   var services = array();
    $('checkbox :checked').each(function(index,element) {
     services.push($(this).val()); //This contains the value of your checkbox.
    });
   var budget = $("select#budget").val(); 
   var timeframe = $("select#timeframe").val(); 
   var message = $("textarea#message").val();
    var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
       // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
    if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
   firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
     }        
 $.ajax({
            url: "assets/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {name: name, phone: phone, email: email, services: services, budget: budget, timeframe: timeframe, message: message},
            cache: false,
            success: function() {  
            // Success message
               $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
               $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append( "</button>");
              $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Awesome!  Thanks for your interest in Nova Development.  Will be in touch soon. </strong>");
      $('#success > .alert-success')
        .append('</div>');

      //clear all fields
      $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
      },
   error: function() {      
    // Fail message
     $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
             .append( "</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry "+firstName+" it seems that my mail server is not responding...</strong> Could you please email me directly to <a href='info@novawebdev.com?Subject=Message_Me from Crownco.net'>info@novawebdev.com</a> ? Sorry for the inconvenience!");
        $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
    //clear all fields
    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
    },
       })
     },
     filter: function() {
               return $(this).is(":visible");
     },
   });

  $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */ 
$('#name').focus(function() {
 $('#success').html('');
});
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['services[]'])  ||
   empty($_POST['budget'])      ||
   empty($_POST['timeframe'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$services = $_POST['services[]'];
$budget = $_POST['budget'];
$timeframe = $_POST['timeframe'];   

// create email body and send it    
$to = 'info@novawebdev.com'; // put your email
$email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".
              " Here are the details:\n \nName: $name \nPhone: $phone \nServices: $services \nBudget: $budget \nTimeframe: $timeframe \n".
              "Email: $email_address\nMessage: \n\n$message";
$headers = "From: $email_address\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do see a problem with your jQuery and checkboxes.

You got:

```
$('checkbox#services')
```

This selects checkboxes with #services id, which you do not have. You'll have to pick up each checkbox value. You could do so with their respective ids q12_x or you could do iterate all the values.

```
$('checkbox :checked').each(function(index,element) {
     $(this).val(); //This contains the value of your checkbox.
});
```

From there on you could push it into an array if you wished.

```
var services = array();
$('checkbox :checked').each(function(index,element) {
    services.push($(this).val()); //This contains the value of your checkbox.
});
```

**Edit**

Added :checked so it will only get values from checked checkboxes.

Comment: I made this change but all it did on submit was add my values to a query string in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do something fairly similar, except my check boxes all had unique id's.  basically you have to check whether each one is checked or not, and put that value (i used 1 for checked and 0 for not checked) into your variable.  here is my code for it:

```
    Guides.prototype.list = ['amOld','folOld','tichOld','bookOld','nebOld','sterOld','byteOld','ingOld'];

Guides.prototype.update = function(){
  for( var i = 0 ; i < this.list.length ; i++ ){
    var guide = this.list[i];
    this[ guide + 'Guide' ] = $("#" + guide ).is(":checked") ? 1 : 0;
  }  
}
var guides = new Guides();
```

Guides can be anything you want, Services would be good in your case.  In the prototype list you would put the id's for each check box.  Your last line of the function might look like

```
this[service] = $("#"+service ).is(":checked") ?1 : 0;
```

and service would be your variable for each id in your list. Now you can pass them in your jquery as individual items (q12_1:q12_1 for example is that is how you put them in the list).  Now in your php file use if statements or any other code you wish to see which ones have values and them process them as you wish.